# Element-wise division on sparse matrix python

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix, elementwise-operations

I have a sparse matrix of size *(n x m)*:

```
sparse_dtm = dok_matrix((num_documents, vocabulary_size), dtype=np.float32)
        for doc_index, document in enumerate(data):
            document_counter = Counter(document)
            for word in set(document):
                sparse_dtm[doc_index, word_to_index[word]] = document_counter[word]
```

Where:

- num_documents = n
- vocabulary_size = m
- data = list of tokenized lists

Also, I have a list with length `n`:

`sums = sparse_dtm.sum(1).tolist()`

Now, I want to do an element-wise division in which each cell of `row_i` in `sparse_dtm` is divided by `sums[i]`.

A naive approach, using the traditition Python element-wise division:

`sparse_dtm / sums`

Leads into the following error:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'csr_matrix' and 'list'`

How can I perform this element-wise division?

Comment: What was `sums` without the `tolist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you need to divide each row by the sum of row, is that correct?

In this case, you'd need to reshape the sum

```
sparse_dtm / sparse_dtm.sum(1).reshape(-1, 1)
```

you can also do it with a pandas DataFrame, for example

```
row_num = 10
col_num = 5
sparse_dtm = np.ndarray((row_num, col_num), dtype=np.float32)
for row in range(row_num):
    for col in range(col_num):
        value = (row+1) * (col+2)
        sparse_dtm[row, col] = value
df = pd.DataFrame(sparse_dtm)
print(df)
```

gives

```
      0     1     2     3     4
0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
1   4.0   6.0   8.0  10.0  12.0
2   6.0   9.0  12.0  15.0  18.0
3   8.0  12.0  16.0  20.0  24.0
4  10.0  15.0  20.0  25.0  30.0
5  12.0  18.0  24.0  30.0  36.0
6  14.0  21.0  28.0  35.0  42.0
7  16.0  24.0  32.0  40.0  48.0
8  18.0  27.0  36.0  45.0  54.0
9  20.0  30.0  40.0  50.0  60.0
```

and then divide each row for the sum of row

```
df / df.sum(axis=1).values.reshape(-1, 1)
```

that gives

```
     0     1    2     3    4
0  0.1  0.15  0.2  0.25  0.3
1  0.1  0.15  0.2  0.25  0.3
2  0.1  0.15  0.2  0.25  0.3
3  0.1  0.15  0.2  0.25  0.3
4  0.1  0.15  0.2  0.25  0.3
5  0.1  0.15  0.2  0.25  0.3
6  0.1  0.15  0.2  0.25  0.3
7  0.1  0.15  0.2  0.25  0.3
8  0.1  0.15  0.2  0.25  0.3
9  0.1  0.15  0.2  0.25  0.3
```

Comment: Thanks Max, your first suggestion works. However, I am working with a sparse matrix as I would run into memory issues with a regular matrix. Therefore, the Pandas' Dataframe suggestion does not work in my case.

Comment: `sparse_dtm.sum(1)` should already be a (n,1) shaped `np.matrix`.  No need to reshape.

Comment: @hpaulj with `np.ndarray` using the for loop I defined to populate di nd-array, you have shape `sparse_dtm.shape` equal to `(10, 5)`. If you do `sparse_dtm.sum(1)` you have a shape `sparse_dtm.sum(1).shape` equal to `(10,)` but you need a shape of `(10, 1)` as you said, so you have to reshape `.reshape(-1, 1)`

Comment: For a dense array, `ndarray` you do need the reshape, or use `keepdims`.  But you continued to call it `sparse_dtm`, so I assumed it was `scipy.sparse` as the OP created.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [189]: M = sparse.dok_matrix([[0,1,3,0],[0,0,2,0],[1,0,0,0]])
In [190]: M
Out[190]: 
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
In [191]: M.A
Out[191]: 
array([[0, 1, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

`sum(1)` produces a (3,1) `np.matrix`, which can be used directly in the division:

```
In [192]: M.sum(1)
Out[192]: 
matrix([[4],
        [2],
        [1]])
In [193]: M/M.sum(1)
Out[193]: 
matrix([[0.  , 0.25, 0.75, 0.  ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 1.  , 0.  ],
        [1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]])
```

Note that the result is a dense `np.matrix`, not sparse.

This could give problems if the a row sum was 0, but with your construction that might not be the possible.

We can retain the sparse result by first converting the sums to sparse.  I'm using the inverse because there isn't a sparse element-wise division (re. all those 0s):

```
In [205]: D=sparse.csr_matrix(1/M.sum(1))
In [206]: D
Out[206]: 
<3x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [207]: D.A
Out[207]: 
array([[0.25],
       [0.5 ],
       [1.  ]])
In [208]: D.multiply(M)
Out[208]: 
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [209]: _.A
Out[209]: 
array([[0.  , 0.25, 0.75, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 1.  , 0.  ],
       [1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]])
```

`sklearn` also has some added sparse matrix utilities

```
In [210]: from sklearn import preprocessing
In [211]: preprocessing.normalize(M, norm='l1', axis=1)
Out[211]: 
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [212]: _.A
Out[212]: 
array([[0.  , 0.25, 0.75, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 1.  , 0.  ],
       [1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]])
```